# How do i print this out?

Tags: java, design-patterns, system.out

I want to print out what cook3 did for a preparation. This should come out: "Pebble putting on a apron". But instead i only get: "putting on apron", so with out the name. I am trying to add a strategy pattern, which I think I did but the only problem is this now.

Here is my code:

```
package cook;

import cook.domein.Restaurant;
import cook.domein.apron;
import cook.domein.classic;
import cook.domein.cook;
import cook.domein.hardRock;
import cook.domein.knives;
import cook.domein.preperation;

public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Restaurant rest = new Restaurant();

    cook cook1 = new cook("");
    cook cook2 = new cook("Glenn");
    cook cook3 = new cook("Pebble");

    rest.addCook(cook1);
    rest.addCook(cook2);
    rest.addCook(cook3);

    rest.doPreparation(new apron());


}
}
```

Here is my interface:

```
   package cook.domein;

  public interface preperation {
          public void doPreparation(String naam);


}
```

This is my subclass apron

```
 package cook.domein;

 public class apron implements preperation {
    @Override
    public void doPreparation(String naam) {
    System.out.println(naam+"Putting on a Apron");
}

   }
```

This is my restaurant class:

```
    package cook.domein;
```

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Restaurant implements preperation{
    List cooks;

```
public Restaurant() {
    this.cooks= new ArrayList<cook>();
}

public void addCook(cook cook) {
    this.cooks.add(cook);

}

public void removeCook(cook cook) {
    this.cooks.remove(cook);
}
public String calculateTotal(){
    for(cook cook: cooks){
        cook.getNaam();
    }
    return "";

}
public void doPreparation(preperation prepMethod){
    String naam = calculateTotal();
    prepMethod.doPreparation(naam);
}

@Override
public void doPreparation(String naam) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


 }
```

And cook class:
         package cook.domein;

```
     public class cook {
private cook naam;

public cook(cook naam) {

    this.naam = naam;

}

public cook(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public cook getNaam() {
    return naam;
}

public void setNaam(cook naam) {
    this.naam = naam;
}




  }
```

Comment: We don't see your `Restorant` class, probably you want to pass a `Cook` instance to `rest.doPreparation(...)`

Comment: Quite unclear. You're using classes Restaurant and cook that we know nothing about. Also, please choose meaningful English names for your classes, and respect the Java naming conventions: classes start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: This my restaurant class:
 List<cook> cooks;

 public Restaurant() {
  this.cooks= new ArrayList<cook>();
 }

 public void addCook(cook cook) {
  this.cooks.add(cook);

 }

 public void removeCook(cook cook) {
  this.cooks.remove(cook);
 }
 public String calculateTotal(){
  for(cook cook: cooks){
   cook.getNaam();
  }
  return "";
 
 }
 public void doPreparation(preperation prepMethod){
  String naam = calculateTotal();
  prepMethod.doPreparation(naam);
 }

 @Override
 public void doPreparation(String naam) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }

Comment: @JBNizet:  In all honesty, as long as the spelling is consistent, I don't mind what it's called.  Convention mandates good style, but if it's readable enough, it's not *too* bad...

Comment: @Makoto: It will never be consistent, because you'll always use standard classes whose name start with an uppercase letter. It's BTW not consistent, even without taking standard classes into account: Restaurant starts with an uppercase letter, and all the other classes don't.

Comment: @user3599415 edit your question. Don't put code in comments.

Comment: I did say the spelling needed to be consistent, not the convention.  Trust me, I absolutely agree with your point, but in the grand scheme of things, it's one of the lesser points to be made about this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing an empty string to your `doPreparation` method.  Here's why:

```
public String calculateTotal(){
    for(cook cook: cooks){
        cook.getNaam();
    }
    return "";
}
```

This method will *only* ever return an empty string.  This is why you're getting the output that you are; it's working as designed.

It's likely you intended to iterate across all cooks in your restaurant and perform preparation with them.  Here's one approach to that.

```
public void doPreparation(preperation prepMethod){
    for(cook currentCook : cooks) {
        prepMethod.doPreparation(currentCook.getNaam());
    }
}
```